# Can't install unzip on RedHat Enterprise Linux Server 7

Tags: redhat, repository, epel

OS version:

```
[root@node1 ~]# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.7 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.7"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.7 (Maipo)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.7:GA:server"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.7
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.7"
```

Tried to install EPEL using RPM:

```
[root@node1 ~]# rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
Retrieving http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
    package epel-release-7-12.noarch is already installed
```

Check repolist

```
[root@node1 ~]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos
repo id                                                   repo name                                                                                    status
epel/x86_64                                               Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                               13,492
repolist: 13,492
```

Install unzip

```
[root@node1 ~]# yum install unzip
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos
No package unzip available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

This is also not work, the same message:

```
[root@node1 ~]# yum install unzip --enablerepo=epel
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that this host has an active RHEL subscription. unzip has been packaged by Red Hat for a long time.